# Kotlin NullPointer Exception Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, import, nullpointerexception

Even after the presence of correct import in Kotlin file, in firebase, I am getting NullPointerException in firebase crashalytics, and it's more in number.

Images are added as part of proof for line numbers, in hastbin or code format i cant add line numbers.

From onViewCreatet API is called, and on line 311, progress.hide() is there from API Response function.

[image: contentLoadingProgressBar in XML]

[image: Progress bar made hidden in API response from Kotlin file]

[image: Firebase crash for null pointer exception]

Comment: Please donot post images, copy and paste the code and surround them in the triple backticks (`). And post the relevant Kotlin sources as well, that directly connects to progress variable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code should be share with the appropriate format such as markdown or tools such as pastebin or similar

Comment: You have a null pointer exception. This question is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/2350083

Answer (score 1):

Would be helpful if you posted the whole code, but I think the problem is that you are calling `.hide()` on `progress` before the `onViewCreated()` override method, so that's why `progress` is `null` when returned by `findViewById()`.